# How to insert data in ManyToMany Rest Api

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I can not find the way to insert data using ManyToMany in spring boot. Can anyone please suggest me how to save data using M-To-M in spring boot and hibernate.

Here down is my code.

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_master")
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer user_id;

    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
    private Set<Roles> roles;

    // constructor and getter/setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "role_master")
public class Roles {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer role_id;

    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Users> users;

    // constructor and getter/setter
}
```

**service**

```
@Override
public Set<Users> addAddressPerson(Set<Users> users) {
    for(User user: users) {
        for(Roles roles: user.getRoles()) {
            roles.getUsers().add(user); // problem is in here
        }
    }
    return users.stream().map(userRepo::save).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

**Postman**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Michael",
    "roles": [
    {
        "name": "Project Manager"
    },
    {
        "name": "Software Developer"
    }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Error**

> "message": "Cannot invoke "java.util.Set.add(Object)" because the return value of "com.rest.RestApiPojo.Entity.Roles.getUsers()" is null"

Comment: 1) You need extra `for` loop to iterate over `users` collection. 2) You are trying to assign argument of `List` type to a property of `Set` type, conversion is needed

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I changed as per your suggestion but I got error `the method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Users,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Set<Users>)` while return `UserRepo.save(users)`

Comment: You are looking for the saveAll function: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAll-java.lang.Iterable-  Also make sure to check out this post regarding turning on batching: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```java
@Override
public Set<Users> addAddressPerson(List<Users> users) {
    for(User user: users) {
        for(Roles roles: user.getRoles()) {
            roles.getUsers().add(user);
        }
    }
    return users.stream().map(UserRepo::save).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

and

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_master")
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer user_id;

    private String name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
    private Set<Roles> roles = new HashSet<>();

    // constructor and getter/setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "role_master")
public class Roles {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer role_id;

    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Users> users = new HashSet<>();

    // constructor and getter/setter
}
```

Comment: try again with the updated code, mind I also changed the return type of `addAddressPerson`

Comment: Change the following fields: in `Users`  `private Set<Roles> roles;` -> `private Set<Roles> roles = new HashSet<>();` in `Roles`  `private Set<Users> users;` -> `private Set<Users> users = new HashSet<>();`

Comment: change `Collectors.toList()` to `Collectors.toSet()` , this should not be needed but I guess you changed the return type of your addAddressPerson function, so I changed it in my Answer as well

Comment: please update your question with the code you have now

Comment: it seems you have not changed the fields `User#roles` and `Roles#users` to default to `new HashSet<>()`

Comment: you don't understand what I meant I guess, I updated my answer, please look at the fields `User#roles` and `Roles#users`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241199/discussion-between-pauld-and-munib-bhanej).

Comment: Much thannks `PaulD` for solve my problem and consume your time. I really appriciate your effort. Thanks :)